# Split special character in 2 columns and merge into multiple rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Nice to meet u all. I have a table named A. table contains two columns named col1 and col2. Col1 having data like TN^AN^KA^ and col2 contains 123^456^987.

Need to remove ^ character and merge two column values into multiple rows like below.

DDL :

```
Create table a (col1 varchar2(20), col2 varchar2(20));
```

DML :

```
insert into values ('TN^AN^KA','123^456^987');
commit;

select * from a;
----------     --------------
col1          col2 
---------     ---------------
TN^AN^KA       123^456^987
```

---

### Need Output like this

TN123

AN456

KA987

Comment: Are you guaranteeing externally that the strings in columns 1 and 2 will have the same number of tokens? Also, can some tokens be null (for example: AN^^YS meaning three tokens: AN, <null>, YS)?

Comment: Also, please include your Oracle version - different techniques and facilities are available in different versions (the newer the version, the better). If you don't know your version, run the following query: `select * from v$version`. Your Oracle version is a five-part number, like 11.2.0.4.0 or 12.2.0.1.0.

Comment: My initial thoughts here are to try to port Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8k function and then use it to split each column into a temp table, and then join the temp tables back. I can't really test this technique, though, so I'll leave it up to someone else to flesh out the idea. The function can be found here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Hi Thanks... My oracle version is  12.2.0.1.0 and TN^KA^AN .....  the special character only one time will come

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 2 colums with only values `TN^AN^KA` and `123^456^987`.. You can use `substr()`:

```
  select substr(A.col1,1,2)||substr(A.col2,1,3) from table A
  union all
  select substr(A.col1,4,2)||substr(A.col2,5,3) from table A
  union all
  select substr(A.col1,7,2)||substr(A.col2,9,3) from table A
```

[Result:](https://rextester.com/TISUK30163)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that allows any number of parts in each input string (not necessarily the same in the two columns, and variable from one row to another). Two consecutive caret characters indicate NULL for that token. I added an ID (so you will know where each output string comes from), and I added an ORD column to show first token vs. second vs. third etc.

In the query, I use the LATERAL clause (available since Oracle 12.1), which allows us to process each input row in isolation, separately from other rows - this makes the query faster and simpler. In the regular expressions, note that the caret symbol must be escaped (otherwise it means "beginning of string"), *except* in character sets (here: negated character sets), where metasymbols lose their special meaning.

**NEW SETUP**

```
drop table a purge;
Create table a (id number, col1 varchar2(20), col2 varchar2(20));
insert into a values (101, 'TN^AN^KA','123^456^987');
insert into a values (102, 'AB^CE^YZZ', '234^000');
insert into a values (103, 'AB', '0230');
commit;
```

**QUERY AND OUTPUT**

```
select a.id, l.ord, l.token
from   a,
       lateral (select  level as ord,
                        regexp_substr(col1, '([^^]*)(\^|$)', 1, level, null, 1) ||
                        regexp_substr(col2, '([^^]*)(\^|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
                        as token
                from    dual
                connect by level <= 1 + greatest(regexp_count(col1, '\^'),
                                                 regexp_count(col2, '\^'))
               ) l
order by id, ord;

   ID ORD TOKEN   
----- --- --------
  101   1 TN123   
  101   2 AN456   
  101   3 KA987   
  102   1 AB234   
  102   2 CE000   
  102   3 YZZ     
  103   1 AB0230
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `REGEXP_SUBSTR`? I slightly modified input data so that return values aren't uniformly set. What does it do? Takes *words* between `^` characters. If delimiter changes, then this code might (or might not) work.

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'TN^AN^KA', '123^45^6789' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col1, '\w+', 1, 1) || regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 1) res1,
  4         regexp_substr(col1, '\w+', 1, 2) || regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 2) res2,
  5         regexp_substr(col1, '\w+', 1, 3) || regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 3) res3
  6  from test;

RES1  RES2 RES3
----- ---- ------
TN123 AN45 KA6789

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr`, `regexp_count` and `concat` together :

```
  with a(col1, col2) as
  (
    select 'TN^AN^KA','123^456^987' from dual
  )
    select concat(
                  regexp_substr(col1, '[^\^]+', 1, level),
                  regexp_substr(col2, '[^\^]+', 1, level) 
                 ) as "Result String"  
      from a
    connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, '\^') + 1;

 Result String
 -------------
 TN123
 AN456
 KA987
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/OJX11236)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp_substr to get the desired result.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,'[^\^]+',1,level)||REGEXP_SUBSTR(col2,'[^\^]+',1,level) as res from A_TEST
connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,'[^\^]+',1,level) is not null;
```